# Wix installer: find SQL tools path

Tags: sql-server, wix, windows-installer, environment-variables

I'm trying to dynamically determine the path of the SQL tool *SQLCMD.exe* in order to create a backup of a database when installing a program.

I've tried searching the registry via

```xml
<Property Id="SQLBINDIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SQLServerReg" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\ClientSetup" Name="ODBCToolsPath" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

It works on my machine, but I end up getting errors on systems with older versions of MS SQL. E.g. the exe is in subdir *110* and not *130*.

Searching the environment path with

```xml
<SetProperty Id="SQLBINDIR" Value="[%Path]" After="LaunchConditions" Sequence="first" />
```

returns all my paths and not just the needed SQL paths.

I need the correct path in order to run

```xml
<CustomAction Id="BACKUPDATABASE" Property="sqlcmd"
  Value="&quot;[SQLBINDIR]\sqlcmd&quot; -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q 
  &quot;
  EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 RECONFIGURE 
  EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 RECONFIGURE 
  DECLARE @cmdpath nvarchar(60) DECLARE @path nvarchar(60) SET @path = 'c:\DatabaseBackups\' SET @cmdpath = 'MD '+ @path EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmdpath
  EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0 RECONFIGURE 
  EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0 RECONFIGURE 
  BACKUP DATABASE BackendSolution TO DISK='[DATABASEBACKUPFOLDER][ProductVersion]_DatabaseBackup.bak' WITH INIT, NAME = N'SQL BeforeUpdate'
  &quot;"/>
```

Comment: Is there a technical reason why you can't just search for all the possible tools paths (with different property names) and use the one you find? Do all the searches then set SQLBINDIR to the one you find?

Comment: I ended up using something quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a C# Custom Action as described in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jschaffe/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters/). There I extract all path variables with `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path");` and make a file search for all SQL paths and finally set `session["SQLBINDIR"] = foundFilePath;`